# I can´t call a column where the name is a date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As a beginner, I´m trying to work on my database and I created some columns with:

```
df[pd.date_range(start="01/01/2019",end="31/01/2019").date] = 0
```

Now I have columns where the names are dates. When I check the columns with `df.columns`, all columns appear and `dtype='object'` for all.

When I call any column that is a string, like df['Values USD'], it returns normally. When I call any of the "date columns", like
`df['2019-01-01']` it returns the error below. How can I call these columns?

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2897             try:
> -> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    2899             except KeyError as err:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: '2019-01-01'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)

Comment: Don't make the column names datetimes. Use them as an index column instead. Basically, you need to transpose your data.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo, actually I need them as columns as my goal is to fill these columns with values depending on the dates appearing in my other columns "Start Date" and "End Date".

Comment: You can still do that, only you'd be filling rows instead of columns. If you absolutely need the dates as column headers, just turn them into strings.